# Swift : Why is the class method struck out

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime

As long as a Swift class extends from NSObject we can pass it to the Objective-C runtime and ask it to introspect it for us.

We have three options:

- class
- classForCoder
- classForKeyedArchiver

. . however class is struck out. (See image). Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation, it's only available in Objective C and not in swift.
See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571950-class

I think this is because the AnyObject gives you enough information (More than the NSObject)
for instance you can do `NSStringFromClass(BaseObject)` in swift instead of the         `NSStringFromClass([BaseObject class])` that you do in Objective C

Comment: Yes, noted that the class itself is an AnyClass type. Interestingly Birdy.classForCoder and Birdy.classForKeyedArchiver could be passed to the runtime, but not Birdy itself. (Next question)

Comment: You were right. I managed to find a proof your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 8):

That's because `class` is a keyword in Swift, therefore any valid method cannot be named `class`. In the same way you cannot create a method named `for`, `while` or other keyword.

I wasn't able to reproduce the strike-out with my methods, however, naming a method `var` (or other keyword) in obj-c makes it impossible to be called from Swift.

**Edit**

I was wrong. It's still possible to call `class` from Swift using

```
var clazz: AnyClass? = self.`class`()
```

However, then the compiler says:

> 'Class' is unavailable: use 'dynamicType' instead

So the answer by Edwin Vermeers is the correct one.

Comment: Useful to know, but doesn't really explain why 'class()' appears in the code-completion drop-down at all, let alone stuck-out.

Comment: yes, you _can_ create methods named `class`, `for`, `while` or other keyword by using backticks in your declaration: ``func `func`() -> Void { ... }``